# Refuting British Israelism

Tags: protestantism, heresy, resource-request, british-israelism

I am looking for materials and/or sources and answers to aid in my research of refuting the belief of [British Israelism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Israelism). Someone at my church is a believer in this and has provided me with materials by the late E. Raymond Capt, who was a proponent of this. After reading these materials, I am completely unconvinced of the claims of B.I. and its supporters. B.I. is the belief that the English, Scots and certain European peoples are descendants of the ten lost tribes of Israel.

Any assistance would be appreciated. If this is the wrong forum to ask this question, I apologize.

Comment: Mathematically, I think it's likely that everyone currently living has at least one line that traces back to Israel. http://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/2002/05/the-royal-we/302497/

Comment: See also: http://www.stat.yale.edu/~jtc5/papers/Ancestors.pdf "[A]ll individuals who have any descendants among the present-day individuals are actually ancestors of all present-day individuals."
However, proving your line goes back to a specific tribe (such as one of the lost 10 tribes) is where it gets more complex.

Comment: Hi Samuel. Thank you for your answer. I am looking not so much for genealogical information. I'm looking for historical, linguistic, cultural and dna research on this. The reason I posted to the Christianity forum is I believe this drifts into the area of myths & legends which can lead people astray from hearing the Gospel and which, I believe, may border on heresy.

Comment: @Samuel Eh, my grandfather has at least one descendent among present day individuals. Is he also an ancestor of all present day individuals? You're misquoting that abstract. Did you bother reading the actual paper? It's about a very simplified mathematical model about which the authors say, "An application to the world population of humans would be an obvious misuse." As far as genetics can determine the most recent common ancestor to all living people died nearly 100,000 years ago.

Comment: @Phil with that said (1) unless this question is about Christianity, which it does not appear to be, it is off topic. (2) If this person you  are speaking to is claiming any favor from God because of physical parentage from Abraham, then they had better circumcise themselves and keep the whole  Law. Otherwise, they are _worse_ off for claiming to be his descendant. Now, we know that the parentage from Abraham that  _does_ afford favor to the Jew and the Gentile alike is that which is by his _faith_, and is through Messiah.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about Christianity, but Hebrew ethnicity.

Comment: @Andrew That's incorrect - British Israelism is a Christian doctrine (according to the forum rules), it's most definitely on-topic here.

Comment: @bruisedreed thank you. I'll retract my vote

Comment: This is one of those things where it's so obviously nonsense that it's hard to know what an effective argument would be!

Comment: It used to be said that you can prove anything with statistics. Now we know you can prove anything with mathematics!  Australian aborigines were isolated from the outside world since long before the time of Nefertiti and Confucius, yet the first comment links to a site that says *everyone* in the whole world is descended from them. I ned go no further.

Comment: @Andrew Expanding on my previous statement, I believe British Israelism to be an error if not an outright heresy. It is tied up with the British Royal Family, the Scottish Stone of Destiny (the supposed stone Jacob used as a pillow when he had his dream), the egyptian pyramids, the Scottish Declaration of Arbroath and several other things. This is being taught in Christian churches (mine included) and I am trying to arm myself with evidence to refute this error. I am seeking anyone on this forum who has had experience with this and can provide appropriate advice from their experience.

Comment: I've just read the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Israelism) on this nonsense. How to refute it? Don't bother. Ask adherents if the verse "Repent and believe the Gospel, and you shall be saved" is not enough for them. If they answer "No", wash your hands of them and leave them to their delusions.

Comment: Please enjoy this sketch [that ends in Jerusalem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ewUJpI_tY0w) go to about 3:00 in the sketch.

Comment: Or [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C79L3vjKAWQ)

Answer (score 3):

A great deal of this move to identify a group of people as the lost tribes of Israel stems from a misunderstanding of prophesy from the OT.  They use scriptures such as Isa. 45:17,

> " But Israel shall be saved in the Lord with an everlasting salvation: ye shall not be ashamed nor confounded world without end."  (KJV)

without understanding the definition of Israel under the new covenant of the gospel of Christ. Some analysis is required.

Under the old covenant, the Israelites were identified by their blood line to be children of Abraham, or proselytes to the faith.

Under the new covenant of the gospel of Christ, all those that are baptized into Christ, have put on Christ, and are counted for the seed of Abraham.

Matt. 3:9,

> "And think not to say within yourselves, We have Abraham to our father: for I say unto you, that God is able of these stones to raise up children unto Abraham."  (KJV)

The blood line was not important any longer, and truly was not important even under the old covenant, as anyone whose faith brought them to a knowledge of the laws of God could become a proselyte, and counted in the congregation.

It was always the faithful of God who were the true Israelites.

Rom.4:16-148,

> "Therefore it is of faith, that it might be by grace; to the end the promise might be sure to all the seed; not to that only which is of the law, **but to that also which is of the faith of Abraham;** who is the father of us all,  17 (As it is written, I have made thee a father of many nations,) before him whom he believed, even God, who quickeneth the dead, **and calleth those things which be not as though they were.**  18 Who against hope believed in hope, that he might become the father of many nations, according to that which was spoken, So shall thy seed be.”  (KJV)

Today, the house of Israel which is saved with an everlasting salvation are all those of the saved under the old covenant, along with all who are in Christ under the new covenant.  If we have been baptized (immersed) into Christ, then we are counted for the seed of Abraham, and we are Israel (Gal. 3:26-29).

Those who seek a DNA strand of the blood line have become confused, and are seeking after the old covenant which has passed away.

I have more material that you can use to support your arguments at my blog at [ShreddingTheVeil](https://ShreddingTheVeil.org). My posts titled *God's Definitions, Part I: The House of Israel*, and *Part II: The House of God* show how these changed under the gospel of Christ.